# How to use Switch in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, switch-statement, syntax-error

I want to use `CASE` in my stored procedure. I am getting some syntax error in my code:

```
select 
   case @Temp
   when 1 then (@selectoneCount=@selectoneCount+1)
   when 2 then (@selectoneCount=@selectoneCount+1)
   end
```

When running, I'm getting:

> incorrect syntax near '='.

at this line here:

```
@selectoneCount = @selectoneCount + 1
```

near the equal.

Actually I am getting return value from a another sp into @temp and then if @temp =1 then I want to increment the count of @SelectoneCount by 1 and so on.
Please let me know what is the correct syntax.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* that returns a *value*. I've no idea what you're trying to do here - maybe tell us the overall goal, and then put the above code inside a larger sample to set the context?

Comment: This answer is helpful in case you really want to do logical flow rather than select an expression http://stackoverflow.com/a/14760234/74585

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `CASE` is just a "switch" to **return a value** - not to execute a whole code block.

You need to change your code to something like this:

```
SELECT 
   @selectoneCount = CASE @Temp
                         WHEN 1 THEN @selectoneCount + 1
                         WHEN 2 THEN @selectoneCount + 1
                     END
```

If `@temp` is set to none of those values (1 or 2), then you'll get back a `NULL`

Comment: Tanx for ur answer , i thought 'case' in sqlserver can actions same switch-case in c#    $(

Comment: use `ELSE @selectoneCount` *if* you want to create a default case when @Temp isn't 1 or 2 and @selectoneCount doesn't change.

Comment: then how to add default condition?

Comment: you can write default condition in "else". If all cases fail it will go for else condition.    @J M

Answer (score 5):

This is a select statement, so each branch of the case must return something. If you want to perform actions, just use an if.

Answer (score 4):

```
    select 
       @selectoneCount = case @Temp
       when 1 then (@selectoneCount+1)
       when 2 then (@selectoneCount+1)
       end

   select  @selectoneCount
```

Comment: declare Temp int 
declare selectoneCount int 
set Temp = 2
set selectoneCount = 0


  select 
       selectoneCount = case @Temp
       when 1 then (selectoneCount+1)
       when 2 then (selectoneCount+5)
       end

   select  selectoneCount

Answer (score 3):

> Actually i am getting return value from a another sp into @temp and then it @temp =1 then i want to inc the count of @SelectoneCount by 1 and so on. Please let me know what is the correct syntax.

What's wrong with:

```
IF @Temp = 1 --Or @Temp = 2 also?
BEGIN
    SET @SelectoneCount = @SelectoneCount + 1
END
```

(Although this does reek of being procedural code - not usually the best way to use SQL)

Comment: nothing wrong with if but i have 15-20 conditions so i wanted to use switch there

Comment: @RamSingh - there's no switch *statement* in the SQL language. As others have indicated, you can use a `CASE` *expression*, but it has to compute and return a scalar value.

Comment: ok thank you, it means i have to use if else for my situation.