# Combining IIF statements in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to combine the following IIF statements in SSRS and cannot seem to get the code correct to run. Can anyone help?

=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) and fields!CallFlag.Value = "1" , "New Record to Dial", Fields!Description.Value,
Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) and fields!CallFlag.Value = "0" , "Do Not Call", Fields!Description.Value, 
Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) and isnothing(fields!CallFlag.Value), "Load Reject", Fields!Description.Value)

Comment: You have 3 IIfs. The syntax should look something like IIF(boolean, TRUE-value,False-value). What you have is IIF(boolean,TRUE-value, FALSE-value,IIF...) What do you want with the second and third iif?

Comment: Just trying to format your code indicates the problem. `IIF` takes 3 arguments (the condition, the true result and the false result), you're trying to pass more than 3 arguments. Its not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi sorry for any confusion, I have a column that has blank values null's from SQL. I want to populate the description field with certain text dependent on the fields!CallFlag.Value = "0" value, if its 1 then fill the blank with "Do not call" or if it = 1 then fill it with "New record to dial"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIF statement reads IIF(boolean, TRUE-value, FALSE-value). In your case you mean: if callflag=1 then "New Record" else if callflag=2 then.......

That would lead to:

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) and fields!CallFlag.Value = "1" ,
  "New Record to Dial", 
  Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) and fields!CallFlag.Value = "0" ,
    "Do Not Call", 
    Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) and isnothing(fields!CallFlag.Value),  
      "Load Reject", 
      Fields!Description.Value
    )
  )
)
```

If you reconfigure that you get:

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) and fields!CallFlag.Value = "1" ,
  "New Record to Dial", 
  Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) 
    iif(isnothing(fields!CallFlag.Value), "Load Reject",
      Iif(fields!CallFlag.Value = "0" ,   "Do Not Call", 
        Iif(fields!CallFlag.Value = "1" ,   "New Record to Dial", "Error on CallFlag Value")
      )
    )
 , Fields!Description.Value)
```

Or even better: if you use SQL-server as your tag indicates, use the CASE command... [CASE command in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220226/how-to-use-switch-in-sql-server)